# Как повесить обработчик change для метода класса

Tags: javascript, ооп, ecmascript-6

Добрый вечер, столкнулся с проблемой привязки обработчика `change`/`click` для метода sumMethod класса `Create` в `ECMAScript 6`. 
Примерный псевдокод проблемы:

```
class Create {

  sumMethod() {
    // тут происходит магия
  }

}

$(".className").on("change", function () {
  sumMethod();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хм, а Вам не кажется что раз это метод класса, то стоит вызывать его **у экземпляра (?) класса**?

```
class Create {

  sumMethod() {
    // тут происходит магия
  }

}

let obj = new Create();
$(".className").on("change", function () {
  obj.sumMethod();
});
```

Как статический метод (без создания экземпляра):

```
class Create {

  static sumMethod() {
    // тут происходит магия
    // Нет this на экземпляр
  }

}

$(".className").on("change", function () {
  Create.sumMethod();
});
```

Можно, однако, и функцией - через `Function#bind`:

```
class Create {

  sumMethod() {
    // тут происходит магия
  }

}

let obj = new Create();
let sumMethod = obj.sumMethod.bind(obj);

$(".className").on("change", function () {
  sumMethod();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

```
class Create {

  static sumMethod() {
    // ...
  }

}

$(".className").on("change", function () {
  Create.sumMethod();
});
```